# Find $\max(PA-PB)$ where $A(1,3)$ and $B(5,2)$

Tags: geometry

> If $P$ lies on the line $y=x$ find $\max(PA-PB)$ where $A(1,3);B(5,2)$

By drawing a rough sketch we see that $A$ and $B$ lie on opposite sides of $P$(Actually the line $y=x$).

I tried using triangle inequality that $PA-PB\leq AB$ where equality holding when the triangle in degenerate.But I am not satisfied that this claim holds when $P$ lies between $A$ and $B$.[By the way I am satisfied that this claim is true when $P$ didives the line $AB$ externally].Is this claim correct even when $P$ divides $AB$ internally?Does max hold when $A,B,C$ are collinear?

How to solve this?

Comment: I asked a simillar question a while back but I mistakenly wrote $\min$ instead of $\max$...sorry for the inconvinience..

Comment: Draw a perpendicular from $A$ to the line $y=x$. Note the point of intersection. My claim is that if $P$ is this point, then $PA-PB$ is minimized. Can you see why?

Comment: And similarly, for maximizing $PA-PB$, we need a similar choice. Can you make that choice?

Answer (score 1):

To make things easier we rotate the picture so $AB$ is on the x-axis with the midpoint as origin, and $P$ lies on $y=\frac53 x$. (by tangent addition formula)

Since a [hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Definition_of_a_hyperbola_as_locus_of_points) is the locus of points which have the value $PA-PB$ fixed, we want to find the hyperbola of maximum constant value ($2a$) with axis $AB$ and intersecting $y=\frac53 x$.

According to the article, a hyperbola centered at the origin has [asymptotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Asymptotes) with slopes $\pm \frac ba$, where $b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}$, $c$ being half the length of $AB$ ($c=\frac{\sqrt{17}}2$, so $\frac ba=\sqrt{\frac{17}{4a^2}-1}$). Since the hyperbola intersects $y=\frac53x$ iff the slope of its asymptote is $>\frac53$, we want to find the maximum value of $a$ such that $\sqrt{\frac{17}{4a^2}-1}>\frac53 \implies a<\frac3{2\sqrt2}$.

Since $PA-PB=2a$, in this case we have $\sup(PA-PB)=\frac3{\sqrt2}$, although the maximum is only achieved at the point at infinity.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion by studying $f(x)=PA-PB$

Comment: we consider the difference of lengths of vectors PA-PB. need to solve this. i confuse it differs from original answer  [link] (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+sqrt((1-x)%5E2-(3-x)%5E2)-sqrt((5-x)%5E2%2B(2-x)%5E2))